# Tensor field notation

Tags: notation, tensor-products

Let $L$ be a finite dimensional vector space. A tensor of type $(p,q)$ on $L$ is an element of the tensor product $L^{\otimes q}\otimes (L^{*})^{\otimes p}$.
How to interpret the following formulation of a basic differential geometry problem: what is the type of tensor $T_i=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ (and the type of the same one $T_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}$)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A famous quote says that "a tensor is what transforms itself like a tensor". To check the type of $T_i(x)$ and $T_{ij}(x)$ we need to consider a transformation of variables

$$x_i\mapsto y_i=y_i(x)$$

and study the transformed $T_i(y(x))$ and $T_{ij}(y(x))$ using the chain rule. In other words

$$T_i(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i}=T_j(y(x))
\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i},$$

and similarly for $T_{ij}(y(x))$. The question is: do you know any quantity with "indices" which does not transform like a tensor?

Answer (score 0):

Your $T_i$ is not a tensor.  One way of making sense of this is by forming the sum $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i$ which is the same as $df$.  This is a section of the cotangent bundle of the manifold where $f$ is defined.  Thus if your $L^*$ denotes the cotangent bundle then $df$ would be a section thereof (in your notation, $q=0, p=1$).